# Can't send email with Thunderbird after some time

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird

I always use Thunderbird, which is awesome! But there's something that's bothering me though.
When I write some new email and take some time editing, correting spelling, grammar, that kind of thing, let's say if I open a new message and leave this message opened all day long and try to send it at the end of the day, I can't, for some unknown reason.

It saves a draft, but I can't send the message though, so I have to open the draft and send it if I want to send some email more elaborated.

Why is that happening everyone ?